# Publish while filtering nested documents

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I would like to know how to publish a collection with its nested documents filtered.

Suppose I have a `category` document that has many nested `post` documents.

```
{
  name: 'myCategory',
  order: 2,
  posts: [
    {
      hidden: true
    },
    {
      hidden: false
    },
    {
      hidden: true
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

How can I publish this document including only `posts` that have `hidden` set to `false`?

I have tried without success: `Categories.find({'posts.hidden': false})`, and do not know where to start. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There's no nice way of doing that. You could abstract the collection using a method:

```
Meteor.methods({
  getCategories: function () {
    Categories.find().map(function (categorie) {
      categorie.posts = _.compact(_.map(categorie.posts, function (post) {
        return post.hidden ? false : post
      }))
      return categorie
    })
  }
})
```

With this you can get a static array. To get something reactive you'd have to put some more effort into it. You could use a [`Tracker.Dependency`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_dependency).

The easiest way would probably be to restructure the documents. There would be two arrays: `posts` and `postsHidden`. That way you could simply use the [`fields`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find) option. In your publication you could do:

```
Categories.find({}, {fields: postsHidden: false})
```